# How to replace the url in a loop using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, range

Just like the title says, how do I write the code in python if I want to replace a part of the URL.

For this example replacing a specific part by 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on for this link (https://test.com/page/1), then doing something on said page and going to the next and repeat.

So, "open url > click on button or whatever > replace link by the new link with the next number in order"

(I know my code is a mess I am still a newbie, but I am trying to learn and I am adding whatever mess I've wrote so far to follow the posting rules)

```
PATH = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=PATH)
driver.maximize_window()

get = 1
url = "https://test.com/page/{get}"

while get < 5:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/form/section[3]/input[4]").click()
    get = get + 1
    driver.get(url)
    driver.close()
```

Comment: You need to update url in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`range()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) function and use String interpolation as follows:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print(f"https://test.com/page/{i}")
    driver.get(f"https://test.com/page/{i}")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/form/section[3]/input[4]").click()
```

Console Output:

```
https://test.com/page/1
https://test.com/page/2
https://test.com/page/3
https://test.com/page/4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
get = 1
url = f"https://test.com/page/{get}"

while get < 5:
    
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/form/section[3]/input[4]").click()
    print(get)
    print(url)
    get+=1
    url =  f"https://test.com/page/{get}"
```

To simply update url in a loop.

Outputs

```
1
https://test.com/page/1
2
https://test.com/page/2
3
https://test.com/page/3
4
https://test.com/page/4
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I also tried the range() function like the other comment says and that also works, not sure what the difference is or if it's only a preference thing. But thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Yeah its technically better going with the range but the main thing was incrementing url in the loop