# InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string invoking url using get()

Tags: python, selenium, url, urlparse, invalidargumentexception

First, I got the total url of all pages. However, When I want to get into each page (page by page),it failed. How could I get into each page?

```
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import urllib as url
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,5)
output = []
for i in range(1,2): # Iterate from page 1 to the last page
    browser.get("https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/search/product?p=%E5%B1%88%E8%87%A3%E6%B0%8F&pg={}".format(i))
    
    # Wait Until the product appear
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='gridList']")))

    # Get the products
    product_links = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='gridList']/li/a")
    
      # Iterate over 'product_links' to get all the 'href' values
    for link in (product_links):
        print(f"{link.get_attribute('href')}")
        output.append([link.get_attribute('href')])
        for b in output:
            browser.get(b)
```

output

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is of *type* *`int`*. You need to convert *`int`* into *`string`* to apply [*String Interpolation*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69921601/replacing-the-url/69926184#69926184) using the **`str()`** function as follows:

```
format(str(i))
```

---

### Solution

So effective line of code will be:

```
for i in range(1,2): # Iterate from page 1 to the last page
    browser.get("https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/search/product?p=%E5%B1%88%E8%87%A3%E6%B0%8F&pg={}".format(str(i)))
```

Comment: Hi,I try to change the code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: ```InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)
```